# Beamer table of contents overly

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, columns, overlays

When i add overly `\pausesections` to the table of contents (Two columns) it dispalys two sections simultaneously (one from column 1 and one from column 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideothersubsections, pausesections, sections=-5]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[pausesections,hideothersubsections, sections=6-]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{Two}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Two a}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\section{three}
\subsection{three a}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Three b}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Three b}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}

\section{five}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{Three}
\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{six}
\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{Three}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{seven}
\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{eight}
\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{nine}
\subsection{Two b}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ff}

\end{frame}
\section{ten}
\end{document}
```

[image: like in the figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trick beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\trickbeamer}[1]{%
        \advance\beamer@slideinframe by #1 %
        }%

\newcommand{\slideinframe}{\the\beamer@slideinframe}
\newcounter{foo}        
\makeatother


\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[hideothersubsections, pausesections, sections=-5]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<+->{.45\textwidth}
           \only<.>{\setcounter{foo}{\slideinframe}}
            \trickbeamer{-\thefoo}
            \tableofcontents[pausesections,hideothersubsections, sections=6-]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Two}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{three}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{four}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{five}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{six}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{seven}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{eight}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{nine}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{ten}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```